# How to access meteor package name inside package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am creating a package and want to use the name of the package dynamically within the package code (i.e. for logging in my /log.js file).

How do I access the variable that is defined in *package.js*?

```
Package.describe({
    name: "author:packagename"
})
```

Since I can not be sure if package names are changing do to separation etc. , I don't want to hard code them.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to do this as the packaging system doesn't give access to this. You can give this a shot though.

Create a publicly available global object using `api.exports`, e.g `api.exports("some_global", ["server", "client"])`;

The global in your package (can be anything else).

```
some_global = {}
```

Then you can run this to find the package name (make sure it has access to `some_global`

```
getPackageName = function() {
    for(var packageName in Package) {
        if(Package[packageName] && Package[packageName].some_global === some_global) return packageName
    } 
}

Meteor.startup(function() {
    console.log(getPackageName()) //=> Should give the package name
});
```

It's a bit messy. Meteor removes most of the stuff mean't to help with this when its in compiled form with the exception of the global `Package` object to remove unnecessary code.

I gave this a quick test with `_` (used for the underscore package):

```
getPackageName = function() {
    for(var packageName in Package) {
        if(Package[packageName] && Package[packageName]._ === _) return packageName 
    }
}

console.log(getPackageName) // => "underscore"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Though it is not an "elegant solution", it works well. So I accept this one and hope MDG gives us at some point more direct access to the package scope from inside a package. Thanks!