# How to get the version of the current Meteor package

Tags: meteor, package

I would like to get the version of the current Meteor package, inside the package files. I can't find [anything](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/writingpackages) in the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/packagejs) about doing this.

`package.js`

```
Package.describe({
  name: 'author:package-name',
  version: '1.2.3',
  summary: 'An example package that does some magic',
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.addFiles('index.js');
});
```

`index.js`

```
// Get package version from package.js here somehow ???
ver _current_package_version = ???;
```

Comment: Have a look at this, it's very messy, because there's no simple solution without hardcoding it. This was for accessing the package's name:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245709/how-to-access-meteor-package-name-inside-package/29249841#29249841

Comment: This is a great idea, unfortunately it looks like the only members of the `Package["author:package-name"]` object are the exported globals. This is a great method to get the name but it doesn't expose the version.

Comment: why not just make that a global variable (`var ver = "1.2.3";`) and then set it in `Package.describe` from that variable, and access the variable anywhere you want in the package? I haven't tried it, but it's a .js file, so it might work.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianFritz, That's a very cleaver idea. I'll try that out and post some code if it works.

Comment: @ChristianFritz, this does not appear to work. I can't use `var` because that makes it local. When I exclude the `var` to make it global, the variable does not appear to get into my other files in the package, so they must be evaluated in different contexts.

Comment: I guess you need to export the version like `api.export('packageVersion')` in your `package.js` to make it available outside the package's scope.